# Why is IntelliSense in Visual Basic NOT showing the Methods/Variables present in Object during Coding?

Tags: vbscript, hp-quality-center

[image]Hi All,

I am new bie in Visual Basic scripting , I started using Visual Basic 2010 for scripting purpose.

Please find the attached screen shot, I have connected to the application using td connect object and after that I should be able to access all the functions from TD object.

Unfortunately VB IntelliSense is not displaying the included functions , I could not find the reason on why it is not displaying the functions in that object.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Regards,
Srihari

Comment: Yes Fvu that is IntelliSense I will correct accordingly, thanks for correctly.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for the suggestion provided, can you please provide an example explaining this , I am unable to figure out where the code has to be modified, thank you.

Comment: Hi David / All, In the Visual Basic 2010 there is a Projects tab in that there is a References tab, in the Reference tab I added OTAClient.dll and now IntelliSense is displaying all the variables and methods that are present in those objects. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying `td` as any type when you declare it. Therefore, without casting it to a specific type or declaring it as a specific type intellisense doesn't have any idea what is it except an `object`.

If you specify `Option Strict On` this will ensure you have identified the type for every variable or give you a compile-time error.  This will allow intellisense to work properly.

Note: The OTA client uses Option Strict Off [`dynamic` in c#] for most of its objects, which will also cause you issues.  You might want to specify `Option Infer On`